# ISC DHCP does not refresh DNS entries

Tags: dns, refresh, dhcp

In our company network we have the following setup:

- a Debian server with a DHCP server (isc-dhcp-server 4.3.1, backported on Debian 7.8)
  which serves client requests from an IP pool
- two Windows DCs for DNS (Windows Server 2008 R2)

The DHCP server is configured to register client address records dynamically to the DNS server.  Our config:

```
ddns-updates    on;
ddns-update-style       standard;
update-conflict-detection false;

allow           client-updates;

ddns-domainname "local.domain.com";
ddns-rev-domainname "in-addr.arpa.";

update-static-leases true;

default-lease-time 7200;
max-lease-time 7200;

authoritative;

[...]
```

Whenever a client gets a new IP from the DHCP, the DNS registration works perfectly.
However, these "dynamic" DNS records expire after some time (a few weeks)...

How can the DHCP be configured to **refresh** the DNS records after a given time interval?

Currently, the DNS is only updated once when a client gets a *new*
IP address (or after a DHCP RELEASE/DHCP REQUEST).

Answer (score 2):

I believe you may need to disable *update-optimization* i.e. by including a line of the form:

```
update-optimization false;
```

That will cause the server to do DDNS updates on every renewal, rather than the default of when something changes.